# Validation Notification Error in Account recovery Page

Tags: bug, account-recovery, validation

I tried to reset my password for my account.

After going to recovery page, I have entered a password without special characters.

> **It showed alert to give special characters.**

Then i removed the password , then i placed my cursor in the confirmation password field.

> **it shows Password cannot be empty over the previous alert**.

[image: Validation alert overlapped]

Comment: yes i face this error.................